# Will an application written for standalone MongoDB work for replica-set or sharded cluster without any changes?

Tags: mongodb, sharding, mongodb-replica-set

Currently we are working with standalone mongodb without any replication or sharding, Now we are considering moving to replica-set for production purposes.

***Will an application written for standalone mongodb will work for replica-set or sharded replica-set without any changes or are there some standalone/replica-set specific features in mongodb ?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the MongoDB uses the default ports (27017 for standalone `mongod` and `mongos`) you don't need to touch your client application at all, it will work in either case.

Of course, when you connect to a MongoDB then a sharded cluster has more options, but the defaults are fine.

Answer (score 1):

> Will an application written for standalone mongodb will work for
> replica-set or sharded replica-set without any changes or are there
> some standalone/replica-set specific features in mongodb ?

Here are some things to think about when an application is to run on a replica-set or a sharded cluster. In addition, replica-sets and sharded clusters has some features not available in standalone deployment (see the *Transactions and Change Streams* topic at the bottom).

**Replica Sets**

A replica-set is cluster with multiple database servers - with replicated data on each server. The topology of the replica-set has one primary node (or member) and remaining members are secondaries (there can be other special purpose nodes like arbiters).

The data redundancy and failover features of replica-sets give your applications additional capabilties - for example, an application always runs even if a server is down.

The data is always written to the primary and read from it, by default. You can configure that the data can be read from the secondary nodes also from your application - this the [Read Preference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/index.html). This configuration can be used by the applications accessing a replica-set in some scenarios (see [Read Preference Use Cases](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference-use-cases/index.html)). This is for replica-sets and has no usage for standalone deployment.

Also, see [Replica Set Read and Write Semantics](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/replication/):

> From the perspective of a client application, whether a MongoDB
> instance is running as a single server (i.e. “standalone”) or a
> replica set is transparent. However, MongoDB provides additional read
> and write configurations for replica sets.

Then, there are some things like, the [Connection String URI](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/index.html), which uses different format for replica-set and sharded clusters - this is used by the applications to connect.

**Sharded Cluster**

The application should not be run in sharded cluster deployment as it is. It will require design level changes - and will affect the queries. Sharding is about distributing the data among shards. Note that in sharded cluster each shard is a replica-set. A sharded database can have sharded and un-sharded collections. Sharded collections are the distributed data.

To create a sharded collection, you must figure a [shard key](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/index.html) - this is the most important aspect of your application accessing a sharded collection. Shard key determines how the queries access particular shard to get the data. So, your application must take into consideration the shard key - the queries need to be created with shard key usage. Shard key affects the performance of your application queries, primarily.

Also, in the sharded cluster environment the application accesses the database via a [mongos](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-query-router/) router - not the servers directly.

There are many other finer aspects when working with sharded databases and accessing for applications - the topic is too broad to discuss here. Changing from standalone to sharded cluster is an architectural change. Some aspects that can affect the application due to migrating from standalone to a replica-set also apply here (as each shard is a replica-set).

Also, see [Operational Restrictions in Sharded Clusters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-requirements/) - these are specific to sharded clusters and not applicable to standalone deployments.

**Transactions and Change Streams**

Features like [transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/index.html) and [change streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/index.html) are available with replica-sets and sharded clusters only (and *not* on single standalone servers). This gives additional capabilites to your applications and can solve complex business logic and scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for your explanatory answer, One thing I am particularty interested in is 'shard key', Is absence of specified shard key will make the standalone collection incompatible with sharded mode or will it be running in an ineffecient manner ?

Comment: You don't need a shard key if the collection is _not_ sharded. As I said before, a sharded database can have sharded and un-sharded collections. All unsharded collections reside on the _primary shard_.

Comment: so the bottomline is that an application made for standalone mongo will run on rs or sharded without breaking although it won't be using their full feature-set. Ofcourse the connection string will change.

Comment: I don't know about that. Your question is general - so I have written the post which would be useful for a broader audience. You haven't said any specifics about the application, its nature, data, etc. It is difficult to give specific answers for a very general question.